# Tensorflow CNN can't overfit on even 20 images

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have some images for binary classification (4400 total). These images are grayscale, 128x128 in size (shape is `(128,128,1)`). I shuffled the data and split them into training and test splits. Pixel values of the images range from 0 to 1. I tried training a CNN using the following code:

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    layers.InputLayer(input_shape=[128,128,1]),
    layers.Conv2D(32, 3, strides=1, padding='same', activation='swish'),
    layers.Conv2D(32, 3, strides=1, padding='same', activation='swish'),
    layers.Conv2D(32, 1, strides=1, padding='same', activation='swish'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D(2),
    layers.Dropout(0.2),
    
    layers.Conv2D(64, 3, strides=1, padding='same', activation='swish'),
    layers.Conv2D(64, 3, strides=1, padding='same', activation='swish'),
    layers.Conv2D(64, 1, strides=1, padding='same', activation='swish'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D(2),
    layers.Dropout(0.2),
    
    layers.Conv2D(128, 3, strides=1, padding='same', activation='swish'),
    layers.Conv2D(128, 3, strides=1, padding='same', activation='swish'),
    layers.Conv2D(128, 1, strides=1, padding='same', activation='swish'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D(2),
    layers.Dropout(0.2),
    
    layers.Conv2D(256, 3, strides=1, padding='same', activation='swish'),
    layers.Conv2D(256, 3, strides=1, padding='same', activation='swish'),
    layers.Conv2D(256, 1, strides=1, padding='same', activation='swish'),
    layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(),
    
    layers.Dropout(0.2),
    layers.Dense(256, activation='swish'),
    layers.Dropout(0.3),
    layers.Dense(128, activation='swish'),
    layers.Dropout(0.3),
    layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
         optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-3),
         metrics=['accuracy'])

hist = model.fit(train_ims, train_lbls, epochs=30, validation_data=(test_ims, test_lbls))
```

Here are the plots for the losses and accuracy over each epoch

[image: Training and Test Loss]

[image: Training and Test accuracy]

I checked if the model could overfit at least 20 images, and it couldn't. Below are the losses and accuracies of the model over each epoch on 20 samples of data.

[image: Model losses over each epoch on only 20 images]

[image: Model accuracies over each epoch on only 20 images]

The model also couldn't overfit on random noise, and I couldn't really figure why this is the case. Thanks for any suggestions or advice!

Comment: Would you re-check if your training data is being shuffled properly? Also, I suspect the problem is somewhere in the preprocessing step. Print and visualize some *preprocessed* images both from the train and test data and make sure they have gone through the same preprocessing steps. Like, one potential and common error can be scaling training images to `[0, 1]` but not doing the same for the test images (or vice-versa). Also, double-check the labels both for train and test data.

Comment: @hafiz031 Thanks for the reply! I double-checked if the data was shuffled properly, visualized preprocessed images both train and test data, their labels, and also the scaling + preprocessing for both splits. No issues so far, but thanks a lot for the advice!